# Google pay through stripe

Tags: android, stripe-payments, google-pay

I have implemented Google pay with stripe. Set up all things mentioned in documentation provided by stripe.[https://stripe.com/docs/google-pay] Google pay is success, after success in onActivityResult the intent is passed to PaymentMethod of stripe and it is also successful. Currently this is as TEST MODE. I am doing payment of 1$ by selecting already added card. But now problem is

1. I am not able see any balance or payment in stripe dashboard, even i have added test bank account details, i don't know why this is happening. And also i have checked response in logs of test data in that "amount" is also not showing in "billing Address".
2. I have tested in LIVE MODE too. In live after press "continue" for payment one dialog appears with **"the selected payment method is not usable. please select another and try again"**

Comment: If you're completing the steps successfully but not seeing anything in the Dashboard, I'd recommend reaching out to [Stripe Support](https://support.stripe.com/contact) since they can look at what's going on specifically on your account. Beyond that, more details about your process and the calls you're making would be very helpful.